# Email to SMS in PHP

Tags: php

Am new to this concept. Am trying to send SMS using the email coding. But am unable to send bcoz am not getting the mobile gateways properly. I need the carrier and gateway for Airtel Tamil Nadu or Vodafone Karnataka. This is the code that i have used...

```
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $message=$_REQUEST['msg'];
    $to = '91'.$_REQUEST['number'].'@airtelmobile.com';

    $result = mail( $to, 'Test SMS', $message );
    if($result)
    {
        echo "Message Sent";
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "Message Not Sent";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to **purchase bulk SMS**(try to search in google bulk SMS provider) and they will provide you SMS api for the sending sms.

Comment: Can't we send SMS for free ? ?

Comment: No , you cant. you have to purchase their service or use websites like www.way2sms.com

Comment: I have a way2sms account... Won't it be useful ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to sms api for this.

First of all you need to search some bulk sms provider. they will provide you the `PHP` or some other languages script. you can embed them in you php code and use it. I am giving you some link so that you can easily find the bulk sms providers

http://www.sarvsms.com

http://www.mvaayoo.com

Answer (score 0):

For email to sms

You will need correct mail address.

I found a list. for airtel tamilnadu.

it is `91xxxxxxxxxx@airtelmail.com`

Link below will display others:
**http://asiancorrespondent.com/675/email-to-sms-sending-a-free-sms-in-india/**

try it using your mail service (ie gmail or hotmail etc). it you receive sms. then try implementing in php. make sure your email code is working properly.

Hope this will help.

Comment: it means they not support. have tried contacting customer care support of your provider